# 41.761441 wlp2s0: failed to remove key (0, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-110)

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, atheros

I've installed Ubuntu 18.04 and this message shows up when I shutdown or reboot my computer and it doesn't appear when I disable the WiFi or turn off the router.

I have a

> Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter

network controller and I've tried to reboot my router and upgraded to Linux kernel 4.18.8, but I still have the same problem.

What can I do?